# Builder Pattern: Why do we need .build()?

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

When researching the builder pattern, the standard pattern is like:

```
new SandwichBuilder().salami().pastrami().cat().build();
```

Where `.salami(), .pastrami(), and .cat()` return `SandwichBuilders`, and `.build()` returns a `Sandwich`.

---

Is it considered bad style to, instead, use the following convention?

```
new Sandwich().salami().pastrami().cat();
```

Where `.salami(), .pastrami(), and .cat()` return `Sandwich` directly, foregoing seemingly unnecessary complication?

Comment: How is pastrami() going to build a Sandwich without a Builder from salami()?

Comment: in this pattern you could put the methods calls in any order, so every method should return the SandwichBuilder, except build()

Comment: Here's an example of your pattern applied: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html

Comment: What you describe is called a [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) ; it's a different approach depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the greatest advantages of the builder pattern is that its built object can be [immutable](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29). With your second example that would either be impossible, assuming `salami()`, `pastrami()`, etc. act as standard setters, or it could be inefficient if they each returned a new instance.

JB Nizet points to Guava's [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html), which is a good example of the latter case. To your point, Guava developers must have felt that "foregoing seemingly unnecessary complication" was enough reason to tolerate a few extra copies during the creation of customized `Splitter`s.

Comment: The non-builder Sandwich example in the OP can easily be immutable. The builder pattern is not required for immutability at all.

Comment: It would be possible, if each call returned a copy of the original. But that leads to many objects being created, and it means that every possible combination of parameters has to be valid. See http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html for a concrete example.

Comment: Immutability isn't impossible in the second example, it would be easy. Methods like salami() and pastrami() would just have to return a modified copy without modifying the original. This is called "persistent immutability". It is what Scala's immutable collections do or what Java String does.

Comment: @user2684301 Yes you're right, and I already edited to clarify that. I originally read too much into the OP, assuming a `return this` implementation was a given. Thanks for your good points.

Comment: I would say that the builder pattern allows built objects to be immutable *without requiring the builders to be*.  It may be useful to compare the efficiency of constructing a `StringBuffer` and appending a hundred strings, and copying it to a new string, versus concatenating the first and second strings, then concatenating the result of that with the third, the result of that to the fourth, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The latter isn't bad style at all, but it requires that the object can be used right away and then added to one attribute at a time.

In some scenarios, it's preferable to collect all attributes first, and then do a one time creation event, without doing a re-create or update for each additional attribute.

In the sandwich example, the latter is probably fine and there isn't a need for a separate builder class. Maybe a GUI control wants to collect all parameters first and then do a one time create rather than recreate/update for each individual parameter, in which case a separate Builder would be more appropriate.